# How to get all factors of an expression tree that affect its output

Tags: c#, .net, expression-trees

Given an arbitrary expression of type `Expression<Func<int>>`, how can I get a list of all objects that could, but not necessarily would, affect the result.

I'm looking for a function like this:

```
IEnumerable<object> GetFactors(Expression<Func<int>> expression)
{
    //return a list of all objects in the expression that affect the result.
}
```

**Example 1**

```
Expression<Func<int>> expression = () => a + b;
```

where `a` and `b` are `int`s, `GetFactors` would return an `IEnumerable<object>` containing `a` and `b`.

**Example 2**

```
Expression<Func<int>> expression = () => obj1 != obj2 ? a + b : c + d;
```

`GetFactors` would return an `IEnumerable<object>` containing `obj1`, `obj2`, `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d`.

Comment: So basically all endpoints (leaves) or do you also want to detect dead code?

Comment: @HenkHolterman: I don't care about dead code.  I'm looking for all leaves, dead code or not.  I think it would be correct to say I am interested in all operands of all expressions in the tree.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to implement a custom expression visitor class like this:

```
public class FactorVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    List<object> factors = new List<object>();

    private FactorVisitor(Expression<Func<int>> expression)
    {
        Visit(expression);
    }

    public static List<object> GetFactors(Expression<Func<int>> expression)
    {
        return new FactorVisitor(expression).factors;
    }

    // Add this method for listing compile-time constant values
    protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression node)
    {
        factors.Add(node.Value);
        return node;
    }

    protected override Expression VisitMember(MemberExpression node)
    {
        if (CanBeEvaluated(node))
        {
            factors.Add(Evaluate(node));
        }
        return node;
    }

    private static bool CanBeEvaluated(MemberExpression exp)
    {
        while (exp.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.MemberAccess)
        {
            exp = (MemberExpression) exp.Expression;
        }

        return (exp.Expression.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant);
    }

    private static object Evaluate(Expression exp)
    {
        if (exp.NodeType == ExpressionType.Constant)
        {
            return ((ConstantExpression) exp).Value;
        }
        else
        {
            MemberExpression mexp = (MemberExpression) exp;
            object value = Evaluate(mexp.Expression);

            FieldInfo field = mexp.Member as FieldInfo;
            if (field != null)
            {
                return field.GetValue(value);
            }
            else
            {
                PropertyInfo property = (PropertyInfo) mexp.Member;
                return property.GetValue(value, null);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Please note that you'll only get the values of the variables, even for member calls like `a.b`.